# Display youtube videos as embed in android

Tags: android, webview, embedded-video

Can any one please help me to embed a YouTube video in the android WebView?

I've tried as follows but nothing is dispayed.

```
    browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webshow);


    String html_head = "<html><body>";
    String load =html_head+" <iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" " +
                "width=\"640\" height=\"385\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/bIPcobKMB94\" frameborder=\"0\"></body></html>";

    browser.loadData(load, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing this

```
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: hey that also not working but when i tried

webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);

Comment: webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true); when added this itz working

Comment: It was not working for me . I tried above code that also not running on my emulator , i am using 2.3.3 emulator..Why is it so ??

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me so you can try as well

```
           video = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    String widthAndHeight = "width='300' height='305'";
    String videoURL = "http://www.youtube.com/v/DZi6DEJsOJ0?fs=1&amp;hl=nl_NL";

    String temp = "<object "+widthAndHeight+">" +
    "<param name='allowFullScreen' value='false'>" +
    "</param><param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'>" +
    "</param><embed src='"+ videoURL +"'" +
    " type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true'" + widthAndHeight +
    "></embed></object>";

    video.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    video.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        video.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        video.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        video.loadData(temp,"text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: That opens the YouTube app for me.

Comment: if you are passing the correct VideoUrl then it should not open the youtube app